# Is there no difference between let and const inside for of loop in Javascript in terms of declaration?

Tags: javascript, loops, constants, let, for-of-loop

I recently came across this code:

```
for (const temp of [1,2]) {
  // do something
}
```

I thought that it'd be better to use `let` declaration for `temp` because this way the variable would be declared only once. However, I also ran this example as well as the version with `let` through babel and this is what I see:

```
for (const p of [1,2]) {

}

for (let s of [1,2]) {

}
```

became:

```
for (var _i = 0, _arr = [1, 2]; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
  var p = _arr[_i];
}

for (var _i2 = 0, _arr2 = [1, 2]; _i2 < _arr2.length; _i2++) {
  var s = _arr2[_i2];
}
```

So babel treats `const` and `let` identically. I'm wondering if Javascript runtime treats the 2 versions identically under the hood. Is the conclusion of this is that even if a variable is declared with `let` inside the loop it will still be redeclared on each iteration?

Comment: Yes, the scoping and life cycle of `let` and `const` variables are the same, and that's generally considered a feature. Don't worry about "redeclaration" as a performance concern; that's the business of people who maintain the runtime (and they're extremely good at it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that it'd be better to use let declaration for temp because this way the variable would be declared only once.

There's a new version declared for each loop iteration either way; this is important for addressing the closures-in-loops problem:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (const entry of array) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(entry);
    }, 0);
}
```

If there weren't a new variable created for each loop iteration, that would log the same value (probably 4) four times.

Choosing `let` or `const` is down to:

1. Do you want to be able to assign it a new value within the loop?
2. Your personal style preference (or your team's preference).

> I'm wondering if Javascript runtime treats the 2 versions identically under the hood.

Yes, other than that you can assign the `let` variable a new value within the loop if you like.¹ For instance:

```js
const strings = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let str of strings) {
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    console.log(str);
}
```

E.g., the only difference is whether the variable is mutable or not.

---

¹ *For the avoidance of doubt: All that assigning to it does is change that variable's value. It has no effect on the array/iterable that the value came from.*