# Query about closures and difference between var and let

Tags: javascript

I have previously posted on SO:

[How would you set the following loop to log like below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391338/how-would-you-set-the-following-loop-to-log-like-below?noredirect=1#comment103129276_58391338)

The answer was to change `var` to `let`.

I am currently learning javascript after having studied python for a few months. I just wanted to see where my analysis is going wrong as I am struggling to apply the concept of block scope and function scope here.

Here is the original code snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000 );
}
```

What I do not understand is, if I delete the setTimeout function bit and end up with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

The output changes from

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

to

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

which was what I thought it should initially do. I don't understand why in the first case the need to use `let i` was necessary but in the second case it works fine with `var`.

Another point of confusion is that, if you take the first code snippet, with the `setTimeout` function, the value of the final `i` printed is 5. This does not make sense considering our initial for loop was only supposed to run till `i<5`.

The last point I am struggling with is that even if `i` was allowed to take on the value of 5, it seems the action (printing i) is done after the loop? I am saying this because `i` starts off at 0, and increases in value iteratively, here we are printing the final value of `i` 5 times. This must mean the computer has gone through the iteration before and then decides to do the action using the final value of `i` but 5 times?

Essentially I thought it goes as follows, we create a variable `i` using `var`, we say that as long as `i` is less than 5, do something, after doing something increase `i` by 1 and repeat.
Instead what it looks like from the first codes output is, create a variable `i` using `var`, `i` increases by 1 till `i` equals 5, do the action as many times as the number of iterations.

Sorry if this question is not coherent but I can't seem to apply the concepts of function scope and block scope here, which I feel is the key issue. Can someone please elaborate on this particular example?

Comment: If possible I would have liked someone to address the specific queries I had? Is there any service on this website that offers that?

Comment: *"I don't understand why in the first case the need to use `let i` was necessary but in the second case it works fine with `var`."*  Because without the `setTimeout`, you're using `i` immediately, so you see its current value. With `setTimeout`, you're seeing it's value **later**, when that code runs. With `let`, in contrast, there's a **different** `i` for each loop iteration (literally a different variable).

Comment: *"This does not make sense considering our initial for loop was only supposed to run till `i<5`."* Because after the last loop iteration when `i` is `4`, you have `i++`, which makes `i` `5`. Then the comparison `i < 5` is done, is false, and so the loop ends. But that's when `i` already has the value `5`.

Comment: Re your comment *"Is there any service on this website that offers that?"* That's not how SO works, but usually in cases like this after pointing to the duplicate with its answers (which you want to read! :-) ) I try to take a minute to post comments (as I did above, but I was still typing when you commented) to help the person asking see how the answers relate to their specific question. *(And I get why SO works this way, though sometimes I really, really want to post an answer instead. :-) )*

Comment: *"Sorry if this question is not coherent..."* Nothing incoherent about the question in my view! Very clearly asked.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101855/is-there-no-difference-between-let-and-const-inside-for-of-loop-in-javascript-in/58101910#58101910) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070682/157247) useful as well. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, just one final query about this is that, with the `setTimeout` function, you say we are using the value of `i` afters it been through all its iterations. I.e, we have completed the loop. In that case I would expect the code to run `setTimeout` would only occur once after the loop has been executed completely and the next bit of code is run with `i` = 5. Instead we see that the code is run 5 times with 'i=5' each time? This makes little sense to me as it means we go through the entire loop and then run the final bit of code 5 times for no apparent reason?

Comment: Yeah, that was poor phrasing on my part. :-) The calls to *`setTimeout`* are synchronous; it's the calls to the callback function you're passing into `setTimeout` that happen later. Another aspect of this is that each loop iteration creates a new callback function, so you end up with five callback functions. With `var`, all five callbacks close over the same `i` so you see `i=5` five times. With `let`, each of the callbacks closes over a *different* `i` (the one that was present in the loop iteration when that callback was created), so you get 0, 1, ...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that answered your question in that comment. Basically, you get the code within the callbacks running five times because there were five calls to `setTimeout` scheduling the callbacks. And then the reason for the `var`/`let` difference is what those callbacks close over. (BTW: This is **not** a simple part of JavaScript, so it's no surprise people don't get it instantly.)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks it makes more sense now.

Comment: Happy to help. I'm writing up something I'll post in a moment that explains it more throughly, just a sec.

Comment: Here's that deeper explanation: https://pastebin.com/rYRPfzgE BTW, I cover this in [my book](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Toys-T-J-Crowder/dp/1119367956/) coming out early next year. Happy coding!